# ¿Cómo dar formato a la fecha y hora?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

¿Cómo puedo dar formato a la fecha y hora que está en cada una de las tarjetas?

Al elegir una opción del *select* la zona horaria debe cambiar en cada una de las tarjetas, el cual funciona bien, pero lo que no sé es mostrar el formato usando *JavaScript* el cual debe ser:

> MAY 7th, 10am PT

Inicialmente se muestra con la zona horaria de *Los Angeles*, luego al seleccionar una opción del *select*, se ejecuta la función y se mostrará la hora según la zona horaria elegida.

Esto es lo que tengo al momento:

```js
//CHANGE TIMEZONE 
let date = new Date();
let PST = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
    timeZoneName: 'short'
});

$("span.webinarDate").html(PST);

$("#webinarTimeZone").change(function () {

    $("#webinarTimeZone option:selected").each(function() {
        let timeZone = $(this).val();

        if (timeZone == 'PST') {
            let PST = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
                timeZoneName: 'short'
            });
            $("span.webinarDate").html(PST);

        } else if(timeZone == 'MT') {
            let MT = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                timeZone: "America/Denver",
                timeZoneName: 'short'
            });
            $("span.webinarDate").html(MT);

        } else if(timeZone == 'CT') {
            let CT = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                timeZone: "America/Chicago",
                timeZoneName: 'short'
            });
            $("span.webinarDate").html(CT);

        } else if(timeZone == 'ET') {
            let ET = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                timeZone: "America/New_York",
                timeZoneName: 'short'
            });
            $("span.webinarDate").html(ET);

        } else if(timeZone == 'AT') {
            let AT = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                timeZone: "America/Anchorage",
                timeZoneName: 'short'
            });
            $("span.webinarDate").html(AT);

        } else if(timeZone == 'HT') {
            let HT = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                timeZone: "Pacific/Honolulu",
                timeZoneName: 'short'
            });
            $("span.webinarDate").html(HT);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="webinarTimeZone" class="webinarTimeZone">Time Zone: </label>
<select name="webinarTimeZone" id="webinarTimeZone">
    <option value="ET">ET</option>
    <option value="CT">CT</option>
    <option value="MT">MT</option>
    <option value="PST">PST</option>
    <option value="AT">AT</option>
    <option value="HT">HT</option>
</select>

<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-5">
        <div class="card">
            <h3>Date</h3>
            <span class="webinarDate"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <div class="card">
            <h3>Date</h3>
            <span class="webinarDate"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Por favor ayuda!!!! :(

Answer (score 1):

Para manejar formatos un poco más complejos, podrías incluir la excelentísima librería momentjs.

De esta forma el formato se acercaría bastante al que necesitas

```js
const date = moment().format('MMM Do, ha')
console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**[Acá](https://momentjs.com/docs/)** esta la documentación para que la puedas revisar.

Nos comentas si te sirvió.